# how to restore very large .bak file (180 GB) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

I have a verly large .bak file (180 GB) which was stored in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and I have to restore it. I first installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express and tried to restore it in MS SQL management studio express but it didn't work because there is a size limit. Does anybody know a method how i can restore the file? Its the first time I work with Microsoft SQL and I have no clue what to do. Its really urgend and I would be really helpful for any help! Thanks a lot!

Umutos

Comment: SQL Server Express has a maximum database size limit of 4GB. You will need a "full" (ie. enterprise, developer, etc...) version to be able to restore a database of that size.

Comment: Does that .bak file contain more than one backup set? I ask because 180GB is a *lot* of data.

Comment: If you just want to mess around with it you can use the 180 day trial; http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need a full SQL Server installation. With that, and if you have enough diskspace, the restore will work, although it will take some time. As you noted yourself, there is a 4 GB size limit on SQL Server Express, so you cannot use that.